# To find the Selenium Xpath for checkbox in <div><input>

Tags: html, xpath, selenium-webdriver

How to click on the checkbox for below code?
I have tried the below xpaths, but these are not able to detect the checkbox and not even showing any error in console.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='oppDiv']/p[8]/div/input[@id='prepopulateCheckBox']")).click();
```

and

using Absolute XPath:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/form/div[2]/div/p[8]/div/input[@name='prepopulateCheckBox']")).click();
```

Please check the code:

```
<p>
    <label for="prepopulateCheckBox" class="">Include the address from the End User Information section.
    </label>
    <div role="presentation" class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitCheckBox" widgetid="prepopulateCheckBox">
        <input type="checkbox" 
               dojoattachevent="onclick:_onClick" 
               dojoattachpoint="focusNode" 
               class="dijitReset dijitCheckBoxInput" 
               name="prepopulateCheckBox" 
               style="-moz-user-select: none;" 
               value="true" 
               id="prepopulateCheckBox" 
               tabindex="0">
    </div>
</p>
```

Comment: From your example, I am not sure that your XPath is correct (because I can't see the parent of `<p>`. What do you get if you type:

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='prepopulateCheckBox']")).click();` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using just the `id`

```
driver.findElement(By.id("prepopulateCheckBox")).click();
// or
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='prepopulateCheckBox']")).click();
```